# Tossing 3 fair coins in R

Tags: r, probability

> **X** = # of heads showing when three coins are tossed.
>   Find **P(X=1)**, and **E(X)**.

Say, I want to solve this problem using `sample()`, and `replicate()` functions in R even though there is a function called `rbinom()`.

My attempt:

```
noOfCoinTosses = 3;
noOfExperiments = 5;
mySamples <-replicate(noOfExperiments,
                    {mySamples <- sample(c("H", "T"), noOfCoinTosses, replace = T, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))
                    })
headCount = length(which(mySamples=="H"))
probOfCoinToss <- headCount / noOfExperiments   # 1.6
meanOfCoinToss = ??
```

Am I on a right track regarding the **P(X)**? If yes, how can I find **E(X)**?

Comment: Assuming you're trying to calculate E(X) from the data, you may just be looking for `mean(colSums(mySamples == "H"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results in `mySamples` stores the experiments per column, so you'll have to count the occurrence of head per column. The probability is then the frequency / nr of experiments, while the mean in this case is the frequency:

```
noOfCoinTosses = 3;
noOfExperiments = 5;
mySamples <-replicate(noOfExperiments,
                      {mySamples <- sample(c("H", "T"), noOfCoinTosses, replace = T, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))
                      })
headCount <- apply(mySamples,2, function(x) length(which(x=="H")))
probOfCoinToss <- length(which(headCount==1)) / noOfExperiments   # 1.6
meanOfCoinToss <- length(which(headCount==1))
```

When you want to calculate a real mean, you can put this into a function and replicate that `n` times. Then the mean will become the average of the replicated `meanOfCoinToss`