# Tossing 3 fair coins in R (2)

Tags: r, statistics, probability

> If ***X*** = # of heads showing when three coins are tossed, find ***P(X=1)***, and ***E(X)***.

The experiment has the following distribution:

[image]

According to my calculation,
***P(X=1)*** = 0.375 ≈ 0.40
***E(X)*** = 1.50

And, [image]

where ***n*** = # of repetitions of the experiment.

**Source Code**

```
noOfExperiments = 10000;
mySample <- sample(c(0,1,2,3), noOfExperiments, replace = T)
outcomeCount <- length(which(mySample==1))
prob <- outcomeCount / noOfExperiments
eX <- sum(mySample)/noOfExperiments
```

According to the above code, I obtained
***P(X=1)*** = 0.2518
***E(X)*** = 1.4917  ≈  1.50

It seems like the value of ***E(X)*** is coming well, but the value of ***P(X=1)*** is not coming correctly.

What is wrong with my code?

**Edit:**

[image]

I have written the following code on the basis of **Edward Carney**'s comment.

```
noOfExperiments = 1000;
mySample <- replicate(noOfExperiments, sum(sample(c(0, 1), 3, replace=T)) )
outcomeCount <- length(which(mySample==1))
prob <- outcomeCount/noOfExperiments
eX <- sum(mySample)/noOfExperiments
```

[image]

---

**Note:** [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55054431/159072).

Comment: An experiment would not involve inserting the probabilities ahead of time. A more realistic simulation can be obtained using `mySample <- replicate(noOfExperiments, sum(sample(c(0, 1), 3, replace=T))` followed by `table(mySample)/noOfExperiments`
`.

Comment: In your original code, you're not using the given probabilities at all - you could apply them using `sample(c(0,1,2,3), noOfExperiments, replace = T, prob = c(0.125, 0.375, 0.375, 0.125))`